# "Could not load image" error after editing the image with Darktable

Tags: 11.10, darktable

I cannot open pictures which I have edited with Darktable.

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Have you set Darktable to import or export changing the file format with expectation?

Answer (score 3):

You have probably stumbled on a issue with the embedded ICC profile "Darktable sRGB" and an image viewer that not supports the profile, you can try strip the image from this embedded profile using:

```
exiftool -icc_profile= file.jpg
```

Let me know if this solves your issue and what imageviewer failed to view the file.